# PHP concatenation precedence

Tags: php, casting, operator-precedence

Is this behaviour correct in PHP?

```
<?php echo '-' . 1 + 1 . ' crazy cats'; ?>
// Outputs:
0 crazy cats
```

I understand that minus is being concatenated to the first '1' and '-1' casted to integer, and not '2' to string.

Please explain why.

What is the best way to solve it?
This one?

```
<?php echo '-' . (string)1 + 1 . ' crazy cats'; ?>
```

Comment: amazed this isn't a dupe.. so +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer, this avoids precedence:

```
printf('-%d crazy cats',1+1);
```

Answer (score 6):

First of all, it is correct, and if it would be different it would also be correct, that's how PHP developers defined operand precedence.
In this scenario, no operand has precedence, so u read it left to right

1. `'-' . 1 ==> '-1'`
2. `'-1' + 1 ==> 0` (arithmetic operations on strings, will try to cast them to numbers first and then do the arithmetics).
3. `0 . ' crazy cats' ==> "0 crazy cats"` (strings operations on numbers, will cast them to strings).

Comment: Argh, you were faster than me :) BTW, Operator precedence is available athttp://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php .

Answer (score 4):

If you want -2 crazy cats, you can set the manipulate precedence with parenthesis:

```
echo '-' . (1 + 1) . ' crazy cats';
```

Answer (score 3):

`echo` also follows the construct of `echo 'foo', 'bar'` which separates the items into distinct statements to echo. You don't have to worry about concatenation order in that case.

So you could do `<?php echo '-', (1 + 1), ' crazy cats'; ?>` and your cats wouldn't care about negatives!

Answer (score 1):

Your verbiage is off. The `'-'` is not being casted but concated.

PHP will still treat `(string) 1` and `-1` as an integer.

`.` and `+/-` have the same precedence in PHP, so the string can be read from left to right.

The above is similar to saying:

```
echo '-1' + '1 crazy cats';
```